# Is there any difference between a syllabic R /ɹ̩/ and r-colored vowel /ɚ/?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, rhoticity

So I have seen that both of them can form a syllable on their own but I don't know the difference between them.

## /ɹ̩/

it is a syllabic R and can form a syllable on its own as in [ˈdɔː**ɾɹ̩**] (["daughter" in Chicago accent](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/560438/387044))

## /ɚ/

it is an r-colored vowel and *can* form a syllable for example in [ˈdɑ̟ˑ**ɾɚ**] ([Standard US pronunciation of "daughter"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/560438/387044))

I also read the answer to this question ([Difference between IPA ɚ, ɹ, and ɝ](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192979/difference-between-ipa-%C9%9A-%C9%B9-and-%C9%9D)) but didn't understand.

Comment: Also see [this question & answers](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9282/28073) on Linguistics SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: In terms of phonetic symbols for American English, no. These represent the exact same phonemes.

There are [several ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_/r/) of making an /r/ in American English, which are audibly almost indistinguishable. One of them is a "bunched r", which is made at the back of the mouth. One can use this method to add r-color to nearly any vowel. The other way is a syllabic [ɹ̩], where [ɹ̩] is a [voiced alveolar or post-alveolar approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_alveolar_and_postalveolar_approximants).

My impression is that originally [ɚ] was intended to represent the bunched /r/, and [ɹ̩] the voiced alveolar approximant. But these two sounds are very close and individual Americans use one or the other or both, with really no discrimination between them, so it was decided that there wasn't any point in using two distinct symbols for two different ways of making the same sound, and [ɚ] and [ɹ̩] are now considered to represent the same phone. The website you've linked to clearly is making some distinction between [ɚ] and [ɹ̩];  possibly it is using the first symbol for a bunched r and the second for the voiced alveolar approximant (so they presumably can tell the difference between these two sounds; of course, they're trained phoneticians).

You can also add a hook after any vowel, such as [ɑ˞], [ɛ˞], [o˞], [ɔ˞], [ʊ˞] to represent an r-colored vowel. Personally, I use both ways of making /ər/, but I also use the bunching technique for the vowels /ɑr/, /ɔr/, and /ʊr/. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel) on r-colored vowels says that you can also produce these r-colored vowels using a "retroflex articulation", but I'm not quite sure that I believe it—I certainly can't do it; I can only use the "retroflex articulation" to produce /ɚ/ and /ɝ/ (which are the same sound in American English, the difference being that /ɝ/ is stressed).

Comment: @Decapitated Soul: a mistake; it's one way to italicize on stackexchanges that use MathJax.

Comment: My impression is that the trend is that syllabic [ɹ̩] is more often used when it precedes a vowel, and [ɚ] almost universally when it occurs word-finally. Incidentally, I believe [ɚ] is very rarely used in British English transcriptions, whereas syllabic [ɹ̩] is. An example would be in the word *gathering*. However, there is nothing principled about any of this. As you say  the two are entirely interchangeable. This is a problem with the transcription system, as can be seen from the fact that this question was asked here in the first place!

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion these two sounds are similar in that they  are both only slightly rhotic, and they are dissimilar in that the second, as the symbol shows, starts as an allophone of schwa, while the first does not, or, if it does, this  allophone is barely perceptible (again, as the symbol would tend to confirm), the sound  being apparently the beginning of an r.

> [Wikipedia - rhotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_consonant) In phonetics, rhotic consonants, or "R-like" sounds, are **liquid** consonants
> [characteristics of rhotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_consonant#Characteristics)
> Another suggestion is that rhotics are defined by their behaviour on the sonority hierarchy, namely, that a rhotic is any sound that patterns as being more sonorous than a lateral consonant but less sonorous than a vowel.

> [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/liquid-phonetics)  **Liquid**, in phonetics, a consonant sound in which the tongue produces a partial closure in the mouth, resulting in a resonant, **vowel-like** consonant, such as English l and r. Liquids may be either syllabic or nonsyllabic; i.e., *they may sometimes, like vowels, act as the sound carrier in a syllable*. The r in “father” or Czech krk “neck” and the l in “rattle” are syllabic; the r in “rim” and the l in “lock” are nonsyllabic.

Comment: If the sound starts as a schwa, it should properly be represented in IPA as [əɹ] and not [ɚ].

Comment: @PeterShor Doesn't it sound at least a little like schwa to you?

Comment: [ɚ] and [əɹ] indeed sound very similar, and both are used (most likely by different speakers) in American English for words like *serene*. But [ɚ] is a single phone (the sound doesn't change in the middle) and [əɹ] is two phones ([ə] followed by [ɹ]).

Comment: They are both only slightly rhotic? I don’t understand.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. In this context, one speaks of r-coloured vowels (or rhotic vowels); by "slightly rhotic" I meant only slightly r-coloured. ([R-coloured vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel))

Comment: What do you mean by only slightly r-coloured?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.I mean that this r sound can be more or less loud or distinctive. It is a little as in diphthongs, where the first part of the combination (e in eɪ, for instance) is always prominent and where ɪ can be reduced to nothing according to the speaker and/or the region. In English, the distinction between diphthong and monophthong is not always clear-cut (Longman Pronunciation Dictionary).

Comment: @LPH Occupying the nucleus of a syllable naturally makes this sound the loudest part of the syllable. Even if this weren't the case, being loud or not doesn't make a vowel more or less r-coloured :-/

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. We are not talking about syllables at all here, not even diphthongs; true, small differences in loudness should not change the quality of the sound, but it seems that a relatively low loudness will make the quality less distinctive.

Comment: How can a syllabic consonant have nothing to do with syllables?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.I wouldn't say that. A syllabic consonant is syllabified as a  syllable, at least in the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, and is thus a full syllable since the vowel sound associated with the consonant (schwa in the l of "label", for instance) provides the nucleus. However, in order for a consonant to have the possibility to appear as syllabic, it must be of a type of consonant akin to vowels, that is, nasal (n) or a liquid (l,r); they have a voiced component.